# How to fetch the thumbnails for a list of videos?

Tags: ios4, ios5

I want create a table view to list all the vedio info. Which I need to fetch the thumbnail images from the internet.

I request the thumbnail for each video when the view loaded. but when a request finished,the notification center will notify all the video objects. so all the table cell will update the image at the same time. at the end all the table cell show the same thumbnail image that finished at last.

The strange thing is it is works fine on IOS5. It only take place when I run the app on the IOS4.

Here's my code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    dataArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"vedio" ofType:@"plist"]] retain];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) name:MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification object:nil];

    ctlArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i=0; i<[dataArray count]; i++){
        MPMoviePlayerController * vedio = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"url"]]];
        //[vedio prepareToPlay];
        vedio.shouldAutoplay = NO;
        vedio.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;

        NSMutableDictionary * data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:vedio,@"controller",[NSNumber numberWithInt:i],@"index", nil];
        [ctlArray addObject:data];
        NSMutableArray * allThumbnails = [NSMutableArray  arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:2.0],nil];
        [vedio requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:allThumbnails timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];

    }
......
}

-(void)receiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notify{

    id pid = [notify object];
    for(int i=0; i<[ctlArray count]; i++){

        NSMutableDictionary * o= [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[ctlArray objectAtIndex:i]];

        if (pid == [o objectForKey:@"controller"]) {

            NSDictionary * d = [notify userInfo];

            if([d objectForKey:@"MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageKey"] != nil){
                UIImage * recvdata = [d objectForKey:@"MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageKey"];
                [o setObject:recvdata forKey:@"image"];
                [ctlArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:o ];

                NSIndexPath *durPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
                UITableViewCell * cell = [tblV cellForRowAtIndexPath:durPath];
                if(cell != nil){
                    UIImageView* iv = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:10000];
                    [iv setImage:recvdata];
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any sugesstion would be appreciate.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you do not get the cells and update them directly. The recommended approach is to update your underlying model (datasource). Then, call the `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method, passing the index path.

The cell should then be redrawn with the new values.

Also note that the simulator, as the name implies, is not an emulator and, in fact, is running off different library than the one in a physical device. Deviations can happen and you should be very careful with assumptions when you are debugging.